# UPDATE SELECT query?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update a row in my table.

```
UPDATE content SET title = $title, content = $content, email = ???
```

The email is the problem, I have the ID of the email address from the users table but not the address, I want to insert the address.

How can I get the email address from the users table in the same UPDATE query?

Users:

```
id|email
 1 johnsmith@gmail.com
```

Here's how my query looks for an insert:

```
INSERT INTO content (title, content, email) SELECT $title, $content, email FROM users WHERE id = $id.
```

Please note, i'm aware vars need escaping/security etc posted the above for a clear example.

Comment: you have to do a JOIN. btw SELECT `$title` ??

Comment: btw SELECT $title - yes, this is the way to do it.

Comment: you mean `'$title'` ?

Comment: you mean '$title' -  as stated: i'm aware vars need escaping/security etc posted the above for a clear example.

Comment: I wasn't talking about escaping/security. You have to tell the SQL engine that it's a *string*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use like this,

```
UPDATE content SET title = $title, content = $content,
email = (SELECT email FROM users WHERE id = $id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why duplicate the data in the content table? Just use a join to get the email address on display:

```
SELECT c.title, c.content, c.author, u.email 
FROM content c 
LEFT JOIN users u 
    ON c.author = u.id 
WHERE c.id = 1
```

Comment: I don't want to get the email address on display.

Comment: Well, you don't need to dispay it per se, its better to use a join to retrieve the existing email address, rather than duplicate it in another table. If the user updates their email address, theres now 2 fields which need updating rather than 1

Answer (score 1):

How do you know which users record to use?

Assuming you have a user_id field in the content table then you can do a JOIN on the UPDATE

```
UPDATE content INNER JOIN users ON content.user_id = users.id 
SET content.title = $title, 
content.content = $content,
content.email = users.email
```